# Trace reveals unexpected evaluations and internal calls for recursive function

Tags: recursion, debugging

I would like some help in identifying the problem in my implementation of the recursive function shown below. But first, a bit of background.

There is a well-known solution to the problem of finding the longest common sub-sequence among two sequences. The algorithm is as follows:

> Reverse the sequences S1 and S2, and call the reversed sequences RS1 and RS2
>
> Define a recursive function getLCS, which takes RS1, RS2, and an empty accumulator ACC and does the following:
>
> If either RS1 or RS2 is empty, getLCS returns ACC.
>
> Otherwise, if h1, the head of RS1, is equal to h2, the head of RS2, getLCS returns getLCS(tail(RS1), tail(RS2), {h1} union ACC).
>
> Otherwise, getLCS returns the longer of getLCS(tail(RS1), RS2, ACC) and getLCS(RS1, tail(RS2), ACC).

My Wolfram Language implementation is as follows:

```
ClearAll[getLCS];
getLCS[{}, _, acc_] := acc;
getLCS[_, {}, acc_] := acc;
getLCS[{s_, t1___}, {s_, t2___}, acc_] := getLCS[{t1}, {t2}, Prepend[acc, s]];
getLCS[{s1_, t1___}, {s2_, t2___}, acc_] := {
    getLCS[{t1}, {s2, t2}, acc], getLCS[{s1, t1}, {t2}, acc]
} // MaximalBy[Length] // First;
getLCS[lst1_, lst2_] := getLCS[Reverse[lst1], Reverse[lst2], {}];
```

The implementation works, but is extremely slow even for short sequences. Running `Trace` on:

```
getLCS[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}] // Trace
```

reveals a lengthy list of internal calls from which innocent eyes should be protected.

As a reference, here is (essentially) the same implementation in `F#`:

```fs
let getLCS<'A when 'A : equality> (lst1 : list<'A>) (lst2 : list<'A>) : list<'A> =
    let rec f (cLst1R : list<'A>) (cLst2R : list<'A>) (acc : list<'A>) : list<'A> =
        match cLst1R, cLst2R with
        | [], _ | _, [] -> acc
        | h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2 when (h1 = h2) -> f t1 t2 (h1 :: acc)
        | _ :: t1, _ :: t2 ->
            [(f t1 cLst2R acc); (f cLst1R t2 acc)] |> List.maxBy List.length
    f (List.rev lst1) (List.rev lst2) []
```

The `F#` version runs much faster. I know that `Wolfram Language` is not nearly as slow by comparison. So, my questions are:

1. What are the shortcomings of my `Wolfram Language` implementation?
2. Why does `Trace` show a call stack that is so very different from what would be considered a normal mental picture of the execution stack implied by the definition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `List` is an array, not a linked list. So an operation like `Prepend` is not constant-time.

Comment: Could that really be the source of the problem? The accumulated list is not always big. Certainly not in the moderate examples I have tested.

Comment: You are right, it's probably not that.

Comment: Possibly the recursive creation of sublists getting passed to the function. If so, could be better to make it `HoldAll` and keep the same two lists for the recursions, passing indices to show where to begin. In general, pattern match based code can be slow as compared to other forms of list destructuring. As for the relative advantage, my guess is F# is using linked lists and not making copies for recursive calls.